# Laravel excel 3.1 при экспорте 0 записывается пустой ячейкой

Tags: laravel, excel

Пытаюсь экспортировать коллекцию, где одним из значений является количество товара. При формировании коллекции получаю 0 как число, но в Excel-файл он записывается пустой ячейкой.

Пример данных из коллекции

```
[▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => "/123ч"
  3 => "Название продукта"
  4 => 0
]
```

В Excel-файле получаю то, что на скрине, т.е. последний столбец остаётся пустым
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавить формат для столбцов, но это не помогло.

```
    public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'E3:E1000' => DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC,
    ];
}
```

Формирую коллекцию следующим образом:

```
$stock    = [null, null, $product->getShopSku(), $product->getName(), $quantity];
$stocksCollection->push($stock);
```

Это не кажется сложной задачей, но это заставляет меня помучиться. Мне определённо нужно записывать 0 как число

Comment: если 0 представить как строку? (string)$quantity

Comment: Этот файл дальше будет передаваться стороннему API, я не знаю, сможет ли оно получить число из строки или просто выдаст мне ошибку, поэтому не хотел бы менять тип на string для числовых данных

Comment: да спокойно стороннее api получит. Просто попробуйте. Плюс не знаю что за библиотеку используйте. https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/ вот всегда использовал и не было никаких проблем с передачей данных в разные api

Comment: Я тоже использую её, ради теста сделал приведение к строке, теперь в ячейке действительно записывается 0

P.S. оказывается другие значения, отличные от 0, воспринимались Excel как общий формат, при записи строкой ничего не изменилось,значит этот действительно должно работать